# Is it hacky to do RF=ALL + CL=TWO for a small frequently used Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax-enterprise

I plan to enhance the search for our retail service, which is managed by DataStax. We have data of about 500KB in raw from our wheels and tires and could be compressed and encrypted to about 20KB. This table is frequently used and changes about every day. We send the data to the frontend, which will be processed with Next.js later. Now we want to store this data in a single row table in a separate keyspace with a consistency level of TWO and RF equal to all nodes, replicating the table to all of the nodes.
Now the question: Is this solution hacky or abnormal? Is any solution rather this that fits best in this situation?

Comment: How many nodes are in the cluster?  I'm asking because I want to understand the thought behind consistency TWO and RF==all nodes.

Comment: @Aaron Actually number of the nodes does not mention in the DataStax docs (or I can't find it). The keyspace runs on GCP. A consistency level of two means two nodes approve requires for success write, and RF==all means the keyspace copies on all nodes.

Comment: Get it! 12 nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is yes, it is a hacky solution to do `RF=ALL`.

The table is very small so there is no benefit to replicating it to all nodes in the cluster. In practice, the tables are so small that the data will be cached anyway.

Since you are running with [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) (DSE), you might as well take advantage of the [DSE In-Memory](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/inMemory/inmemTOC.html) feature which allows you to keep data in RAM to save from disk seeks. Since your table can easily fit in RAM, it is a perfect use case for DSE In-Memory.

To configure the table to run In-Memory, set the table's compaction strategy to `MemoryOnlyStrategy`:

```
CREATE TABLE inmemorytable (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ( ... )
) WITH compaction= {'class': 'MemoryOnlyStrategy'}
     AND caching = {'keys':'NONE', 'rows_per_partition':'NONE'};
```

To alter the configuration of an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE inmemorytable
    WITH compaction= {'class': 'MemoryOnlyStrategy'}
    AND caching = {'keys':'NONE', 'rows_per_partition':'NONE'};
```

Note that tables configured with DSE In-Memory are still persisted to disk so you won't lose any data in the event of a power outage or service disruption. In-Memory tables operate the same as regular tables so the same backup and restore processes still apply with the only difference being that a copy of the data is kept in memory for faster read performance.

For details, see [DataStax Enterprise In-Memory](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/inMemory/inmemTOC.html). Cheers!